# This lack of reliability, can be ..?

Tags: word-choice

How to say the factors are responsible for the lack of credibility?

> This lack of reliability can be **imputed** to several factors.

"imputed" is probably wrong. What word should I use, in an academic environment?

Comment: I would not say that "imputed" is wrong, but I would agree that "attributed" is far more commonly used.

Comment: [imputed](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/impute?q=imputed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about *attributed*, *ascribed*, *put down*, *traced back*?

By the way, the comma in your sentence is completely uncalled for.

Comment: +1 for the comma comment - that comma really needs to go :)

Answer (score 1):

blamed on, caused by one or more of, caused by any of, placed at the feet of, pinned on?